# How to write query to cloud search to get result on partial text match

Tags: amazon-web-services, ruby-on-rails-4, amazon-cloudsearch

I'm adding a search by name options in my current CloudSeach integration. I'm searching for a key `name` by passing `phrase field=name 'Stratosphere Hotel, Casino'` for `filter_query`. This is working fine if I have an exact name match. But my search input for `name` is coming from google maps API and the data in my CloudSeach may not have an exact match with values in `name` key.

ie.

```
search input: DoubleTree by Hilton Hotel Irvine - Spectrum 
CloudSeach value: DoubleTree by Hilton Irvine - Spectrum

search input: Candlewood Suites OC Airport- Irvine West Extended Stay Hotel 
CloudSeach value: Candlewood Suites OC Airport-Irvine West
```

I have looked into `near, fuzzy logic` docks but I'm fairly new to CloudSeach.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cloudsearch/latest/developerguide/searching-text.html
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cloudsearch/latest/developerguide/filtering-results.html

Is there any way to do a partial word search and match it and return those data. BTW 80% the data is matching names with CloudSeach's uploaded data, it's just around 20% data I'm having a problem searching with.